# Oracle 11g connectivity with java in Netbeans 7.1

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, oracle11g

I have successfully connected my Oracle 11g XEdatabase with java in Netbeans 7.1.

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
System.out.println("DRIVER LOADED!");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "system", "acpsa") ;
System.out.println("CONNECTION ESTABLISHED!");
```

Now I want to access a table `employee(fname,lname,ssn)`, retrieving all records and displaying them.

When I add this code:

```
Statement stmt;
stmt=(Statement)conn.createStatement();
String qq = "select fname,ssn from employee where lname='tank';";
ResultSet rs = (ResultSet)stmt.executeQuery(qq);
while(rs.next()){
    System.out.println(rs.getString("fname") + "\t" + rs.getString("ssn"));
}
```

I get the following error:

> Error :java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character

This might be due to the fact the we can't access multiple rows in oracle.

How can I access the `employee` table in Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the semicolon from the query.

```
String qq = "select fname,ssn from employee where lname='tank'";
```

By the way, all those casts `(Statement)` and `(ResultSet)` are unnecessary.